# How to limit a table based on 2 categories from a particular column in SQL / Hive SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, databricks, delta-lake

I have a table which contains a column called *region*, the *region* contains 2 values - ***Mexico and USA***.
I want to download a sample subset of the table, but what I need is the values should be based on both USA and MEXICO.

---

I have tried these queries - `SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE REGION LIKE 'us%'  or REGION LIKE 'mexic%'`

`SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE REGION IN ("us", "mexico") LIMIT 1000`

The AND condition doesn't works in the above query. Also the above query only returns one of the regions. What I need is 50% of USA and 50% MEXICO in the sample table. Can this be done using any window functions or any simpler method would also be helpful.

[image: Sample table]

> P.S - The sample record is to be showcased in a DECK (PPT) presentation.

---

Comment: Do you want to limit based on the minimum amount of regions? (like if there is 4 Mexico and 3 USA you want to return 3 Mexico and 3 USA) And do you have a snippet of the table please ?

Comment: Hi @Paul its a huge table with millions of records, what i want exactly is a smaller subset of the data lets say 1k records but for both the regions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an arbitrary amount of rows, you can use unions :

```sql
(SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE REGION LIKE 'mexic%' LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE REGION LIKE 'us%' LIMIT 5);
```

Comment: Throws out a parse exception EOF. If i remove the first LIMIT 5, it still gives me only US records

Comment: Can you provide an example with a fake input and the expected output please ? To be sure that I understand that data you're dealing with

Comment: Sure editing the question to add the dummy table

Comment: There was a small mistake (I hadn't touched SQL in a while) can you look at my edited answer @MohseenMulla ?

Comment: Not sure if the parse exception will be fixed though, I don't really know where it is coming from :(